# RabbitMQ exactly or all ha-mode

Tags: rabbitmq

I need help from some rabbit experts around the **ha-mode** being set to **exactly**

At the moment we have a cluster of 3 nodes as shown below:

[image]

We have a policy setup as shown below:

[image]

I can see that a queue is mirrored to nodes 1 and 2 as shown below:

[image]

**Question**

Is there the case that node 3 could become the primary? and then not have the mirrored queue data in it? I'm worried that we should be mirroring to all 3 nodes not just the primary and one of the secondary nodes.